# Returning unique_ptr<Object> as unique_ptr<const Object>

Tags: c++, c++11, return, constants, unique-ptr

I have a method like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<const Stats> Table::GetStats() const {
  std::unique_ptr<Stats> result;
  // ...
  // Prepare stats. Under some conditions an exception may be thrown.
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't compile:

> error: cannot bind ‘std::unique_ptr’ lvalue to ‘std::unique_ptr&&’

I can make it compile by using the following bypass:

```
return std::unique_ptr<const Stats>(result.release());
```

But it seems a bit as doing something excessive. I cannot understand, what's wrong with the first piece of code from C++'s point of view? Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: compiler version? works for me. https://godbolt.org/g/DZak6n

Comment: @RichardHodges, gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u1) 4.9.2

Comment: @RichardHodges probably you get RVO without OP's `// Prepare stats. Under some conditions an exception may be thrown.`

Comment: @AlexeyUsachov, what is "OP"?

Comment: @Alexey that's old. It will be buggy. you could try `return { std::move(result) };`

Comment: @RichardHodges Original poster, post owner

Comment: @RichardHodges, stupid me, completely forgot about `move`. It works for me even w/o initializer list. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work fine, because in [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes):

(emphasis mine)

> (since C++11)
>
> If expression is an lvalue expression and the conditions for copy
>   elision are met, or would be met, except that expression names a
>   function parameter, then overload resolution to select the constructor
>   to use for initialization of the returned value is performed twice:
>   **first as if expression were an rvalue expression** (thus it may select
>   the move constructor or a copy constructor taking reference to const),
>   and if no suitable conversion is available, overload resolution is
>   performed the second time, with lvalue expression (so it may select
>   the copy constructor taking a reference to non-const).
>
> The above rule applies even if the function return type is different
>   from the type of expression (copy elision requires same type)

That means, even `result` is an lvalue, it'll be regarded as an rvalue at first, then the following [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) would be selected, it could convert `std::unique_ptr<Stats>` to `std::unique_ptr<const Stats>`.

> ```
> template< class U, class E >
> unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;
> ```

It seems gcc4.9.2 doesn't behave this way (i.e. treating the expression as an rvalue expression firstly); [gcc 9](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NH7RxSDYjHOhmcfM) just works fine.

As [@RichardHodges commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186853/returning-unique-ptrobject-as-unique-ptrconst-object/50187051#comment87390479_50186853), you could use `std::move` as the [workaround](https://wandbox.org/permlink/roapDfniDZwQe3y6).

Comment: The compiler isn't required (prior to C++17 that is) to do any copy elision, so it behaves correctly. `std::move` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: @Pezo It just requires "conditions for copy elision are met ...", not that copy elision is actually applied.

Comment: Are there conditions for copy elision in the standard? Is it defined but not required?

Comment: @Pezo I'm not sure I understand your questions entirely. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision for conditions where the compiler is allowed to perform copy elision. As you said, from C++17 on it is mandatory.

Comment: I see, there's conditions where it's allowed because it can change the observable behavior. I always thought about it in terms of as-if, then it would always be allowed.